# send two alert data from php back to my script

Tags: php, ajax

I have 2 php files :-

first one:=

```
<?php
echo "Connected successfully  ";

echo "here";

?>
```

Second one=

```
function retrieveData(){
$.post('retrieveData.php',{}, function(data){
window.alert (data)
 });
}
```

the problem is here that only one alert value :- `Connected successfully` shown.

I need data to alert each time it finds echo in the other `php` file separately.

in other words I wish I will 2 alerts one with `Connected successfully`
and other with `here`

please help

Comment: Use a proper title not code

Comment: Search for sending JSON data as reponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `echo` directly it's complicated to send two or more alert data at a time (complicated but feasible).

You can do it in below simple way:-

First page (PHP page):

```
<?php
$data = array(); // create an array
$data[] =  "Connected successfully  "; // add all echo data to the array

$data[] =  "heree"; // add all echo data to the array

echo json_encode($data); // encode the array into json and send it back to jQuery code as a response
?>
```

Second page:

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    retrieveData();
   function retrieveData(){
        $.post('abc.php',{}, function(data){
            var new_data = $.parseJSON(data); // decode json data and covert it to jQuery array

            $.each(new_data, function(index, element) { // iterate over array
               window.alert(element); // alert each element of the array
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Output at my local end:

1. http://prntscr.com/ceofn6
2. http://prntscr.com/ceofsd

As you ask in comment do like below:

```
$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $data[] = $row["input"]; // make sure that db table column name is "input"
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $data[] = $row["input"]; echo json_encode($data); } what can I do in this case ? I just wanted each $row["input"]; ur code works fine thanks! but when i try to apply for the info i get from the database it does not work and Idk why

Comment: Man if you have something then why didn't you ask with that. you provide us little data and we will gave you answer accordingly. Please ask a new question with complete input and expected output.

Comment: @CSStudent  i have added some data regarding your question. check once

Comment: i have asked another question

Answer (score 2):

It is other variant

first file retrieveData.php

```
<?php
$array = array("message"=>"Connected successfully","text"=>"heree");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

second file index.php

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 retrieveData();

   function retrieveData(){
     $.post('retrieveData.php',{}, function(data){
        data=$.parseJSON(data);
        window.alert (data.message);
        window.alert (data.text);
     });
  }
 });
```

Comment: if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row["input"];
    echo json_encode($data);
    }    what can I do in this case ? I just wanted each $row["input"]; to be sent separately. (is there another way rather than looping ? )